# R: Convert dyamic date format to date class?

Tags: r, class, date, calendar, lubridate

I have a data set that contains a simple column consisting of dates, like this:

```
      Dates
1  2012/04/10
2  2012/03/30
3  2012/03/24
4  2012/03/25
5  2012/04/10
6  2012/04/14
7  2012/04/21
```

My desired output is this:

```
      Dates        DateName
1  2012/04/10     April 2012
2  2015/03/30     March 2015
3  2011/03/24     March 2011
4  2016/12/25     December 2016
5  2014/06/10     June 2014
6  2014/05/14     May 2014
7  2018/07/21     August 2018
```

To do this I used the following code:

```
dt$Dates <- as.Date(dt$Dates)
dt$DateName <- format(dt$Dates,"%B %Y")
```

Whilst this works fine, my new column comes out a character class. **I wish for this to come out as a date class instead.** This is because I cannot sort this column by calendar date. Rather, it sorts alphabetically.

**Is there a way to class or re-class my new date format as some sort of date or calander class?**

(I'm not necessarily looking for a base-R solution).

(If possible, I would also highly prefer to keep my new format as is).

I have tried the following lines of code and more, but these only return errors.

```
dt$DateName <- format.Date(dt$Dates,"%B %Y")

dt$DateName <- format.POSIXlt(dt$Dates,"%B %Y")

dt$DateName <- format.difftime(dt$Dates,"%B %Y")

dt$DateName <- as.Date(dt$Dates, format ="%B %Y")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert dates to `yearmon` class :

```
dt$month_year <- zoo::as.yearmon(dt$Dates, "%Y/%m/%d")
dt
#       Dates month_year
#1 2012/04/10   Apr 2012
#2 2012/03/30   Mar 2012
#3 2012/03/24   Mar 2012
#4 2012/03/25   Mar 2012
#5 2012/04/10   Apr 2012
#6 2012/04/14   Apr 2012
#7 2012/04/21   Apr 2012

class(dt$month_year)
#[1] "yearmon"
```

You can then sort them

```
dt[order(dt$month_year), ]

#       Dates month_year
#2 2012/03/30   Mar 2012
#3 2012/03/24   Mar 2012
#4 2012/03/25   Mar 2012
#1 2012/04/10   Apr 2012
#5 2012/04/10   Apr 2012
#6 2012/04/14   Apr 2012
#7 2012/04/21   Apr 2012
```

**data**

```
dt <- structure(list(Dates = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L
), .Label = c("2012/03/24", "2012/03/25", "2012/03/30", "2012/04/10", 
"2012/04/14", "2012/04/21"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```